# Correctly place table into 4NF?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

**Question:**

Place the PERSON relation into 4NF where

PERSON (Name, Sibling, Shoe_Size)
Assume the following functional dependencies exist:

Name -->--> Sibling

Name --> Shoe_Size

..................

Is what I have come up with below a correct version of the table in 4NF? Still getting my head wrapped around Normalization.

LIST THE MULTIVALUED DEPENDENCIES

**Name -->--> Sibling**

SPLIT MULTIVALUE DEPENDENCIES INTO OWN TABLE

**PERSON_2([PK]PersonName, Shoe_Size)**

**SIBLING([FK]PersonName, SiblingName)**

STEP TWO:  LIST THE FUNCTIONAL DEPENDENCIES

**PersonName -> (Shoe_Size, SiblingName)**

STEP THREE:  LIST THE INITIAL CANDIDATE KEYS

**PersonName**

STEP SEVEN:  STATE THE FINAL TABLES AND CREATE REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY CONSTRAINTS

**PERSON_2([PK]PersonName, Shoe_Size)**

**SIBLING([FK]PersonName, SiblingName)**

..

**WHERE SIBLING.PersonName must exist in PERSON_2.PersonName.**

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you have forgotten is the constraint

PERSON_2.PersonName must exist in SIBLING.

Otherwise your resulting database design is not fully equivalent to the original one.

(Many times it's also a sign that your original design wasn't very apt to address the business problem at hand to begin with, but normalization theory isn't concerned with aptness of original designs.)